# Can you please help me embed my form script into my FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Good Morning,

I am having trouble figuring out how to embed my form script into my FancyBox.

I am new to this, so apologize in advance.  I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find the correct answer.

I have a very simple test page created just so I can use it to figure out how this all works.

Basically, I need to replace the image that pops up with my form.

Here is my form script that I need to embed:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="//js.hubspot.com/forms/current.js"></script>

<script>

  hbspt.forms.create({ 

    portalId: '206683',

    formId: 'ecaa931c-1fc4-4b96-8aea-b040169f449d'

  });

</script>
```

And here is my test page:

`http://online.saintleo.edu/FancyBox2/FancyBox2.html`

Thank you in advance. You time and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that if you test this from your file system you will need to add http: in front of the //js....

Comment: Here is the same question on another site: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1241676?tstart=0

Comment: Like this?<script charset="utf-8" src="http://online.saintleo.edu/FancyBox2/current.js"></script>

<script>

  hbspt.forms.create({ 

    portalId: '206683',

    formId: 'ecaa931c-1fc4-4b96-8aea-b040169f449d'

  });

</script>

Comment: Yes, that is my post.

Comment: No I meant change `src="//js` to `src="http://js` if you are testing from harddisk

Comment: can you put the form script in an html page and change the href to that page?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Updated to:  <script charset="utf-8" src="http://js.hubspot.com/forms/current.js"></script>

<script>

  hbspt.forms.create({ 

    portalId: '206683',

    formId: 'ecaa931c-1fc4-4b96-8aea-b040169f449d'

  });

</script>

Comment: Tried putting into an HTML page but it opens in a new page rather than within the fancybox.

Comment: mplungjan- so weird.... fancybox is working here, but form is also in the page body.....why?   http://online.saintleo.edu/FancyBox2/FancyBox2%20-%20Copy.html

Comment: I meant `<a class="iframe" href="pagewithformgeneration.html">`

Comment: Again, back to "Tried putting into an HTML page but it opens in a new page rather than within the fancybox."  It doesn't work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answering to get the formatting

Main page:

```html
<table width="1264px" height="100" border="0" bgcolor="#0A3D32">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://online.saintleo.edu/main-logo.png" width="334" height="94" /></td>
    <td>
      <a class="iframe" href="#form"><img src="https://online.saintleo.edu/RequestInfoButton-Test.jpg" width="127" height="36" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="form" style="display:none">
  <iframe height="500" src="form.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

form.html

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://js.hubspot.com/forms/current.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: '206683',
    formId: 'ecaa931c-1fc4-4b96-8aea-b040169f449d'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks mplungjan,  feel like I am getting closer   
http://online.saintleo.edu/FancyBox2/FancyBox2%20-%20Copy.html   ....but now getting the following error: This page can't be displayed

•Make sure the web address is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Fix connection problems

Comment: .../FancyBox2/form.html is not found

Comment: Ok, made sure it was there, but do you see it opening in a whole page vs. the box?

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. Did I miss something?  http://online.saintleo.edu/FancyBox2/FancyBox2%20-%20Copy.html

Comment: NOW see update. See I changed href="#form" and put the iframe with form.html in a hidden div